# Eclipse Less editor: How to @import external less file

Tags: eclipse, import, less

In Eclipse PHP Luna I'm using the less plugin from [normalesup](http://www.normalesup.org/~simonet/soft/ow/eclipse-less.en.html) (1.0.22) to edit my less files.

I would like to import a less file from outside my project. I'm using the following syntax:

```
@import "../../other-project/less/style.less";
```

I've also tried all kinds of settings in Eclipse like Resources/Linked Resources, LESS/Include Paths, PHP/Include Paths,  etc. but to no avail.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Btw. An absolute path generates an NPE at LessImportingStatementFinder.java:233